# Where do i set the return URL in Paypal sandbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

Have an ASP .Net form built with C#.

Not sure what's going on here. I am sending a test transaction and setting the return URL within my Paypal account but it always redirects to the wrong URL after making a payment (So i get to paypal sandbox and make a payment using a test PP account but when it redirects it goes to the wrong URL).

Heres whats being sent to Paypal

```
action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="name.domain.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="item"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="17.00"/>
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"/>
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://example.com/Cancel"/>
<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://example.com/shopwithus"/>
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://example.com/response/"/>
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB"/>
<input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="http://example.com/pic.gif"/>
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="ab12963257"/>
```

I have checked the below areas once logging using my sandbox account on paypal's site

```
businessprofile/settings
businessprofile/mymoney
businessprofile/mysettings
businessprofile/mytools
```

I see the following options

```
Instant Payment Notification (IPN) - On
```

Under Current settings

```
Notification URL
```

Which ive set with the URL i would like it to go to.

Website preferences - Also set to the URL it needs to go to.

With the above actions taken it still takes me to the wrong URL. By saying wrong URL i mean an URL that i mustve set in the past somewhere.

Does anyone know where i need to look to change the return URL after a successful payment?

Comment: where is going ? what is the wrong url ?

Comment: @Aristos The wrong URL is a URL i have set during testing one of my OTHER test sites. So it returns the user back to another test site i created. I mustve set this value somewhere but not sure where to look for this setting.